# Simplified facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I followed certain links like :http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect--net-12302 and also many others.I made this simplified code out of it. 
It gives no errors but, the issue is login link is never turned to logout.
Error in URL is error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&code=..some long string here..
I have already set the app as public and available to all users.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
    include 'libs/facebook.php';
    $facebook=new facebook(array(
       'appId'=> '###',
       'secret'=>'***',
       'cookie'=>false
    ));
    $user=$facebook->getUser();
    $me=null;
    if($user){
       try{
         $me=$facebook->api('/me');
       }
       catch(FacebookApiException $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
       }
    }
    if($me){
       echo $me;
       $logoutUrl=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
       echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
       //echo "in log out url";
    }
    else{
       echo "$me";
       $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
       echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
      // echo "login url";
    }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pls format your question properly the next time so that people here can at least take interest in looking at your problem

Comment: Second thing, never follow the third party tutorials. There is already the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com) by facebook - follow this. They have explained each and every bit in a very detailed way with examples.

Comment: But I can see the `Logout` button after loggin in, when used the same code

Comment: mydomain/error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&code=some long string .This the error i am getting at url

Comment: @SahilMittal any suggestions? I still can't see logout button

Answer (score 0):

There could be any reason like:

- `App_id` and `App_secret` may be wrong that you've entered in the code. Pl re-check
- Chec kthe `Site URL` in the App settings- is it configured correctly?

Comment: I guess problem is with hosting. No external connection allowed.